# What would be wrong with the SQL Query?

Tags: php

What can I do to fix this SQL Query?

```
$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = " . $email . "");
```

Comment: My guess is that you need to add quotes around the `$email` string. I hope that string is sanitised...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = '" . $email . "'");
```

It's missing single quotes `'` that should be enclosing the `$email` value since it is a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = '" . $email . "'");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = '$email'");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = '" . $email . "'");
```

You need to use '' for string variables

Wrong: `SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = email@email.email`

Ok: `SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = 'email@email.email'`

Answer (score 0):

Escape the parameter.

```
$q = $db->sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = '" . $email . "'");
```